Почему Qt не воспринимает русские буквы в классе который наследует QDialog
Почему Qt не воспринимает русские буквы в классе который наследует QDialog? Шрифт поддерживает русские буквы. Когда пытаюсь присвоить русские буквы для QPushButton или QComboBox приложение либо не компилируется, либо вместо букв я вижу вопросики на кнопке. Когда я делаю тоже самое в классе унаследованном от QWidget то все ок.
#include "AddExpenses.h"
#include "CalendarDialog.h"
#include <QDateEdit>
#include <QFontDatabase>

AddExpenses::AddExpenses(QWidget* parent) : QDialog(parent) {
    int fontId = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/ofont.ru_Angeme.ttf");
    QString fontFamily = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(fontId).at(0);
    QFont customFont(fontFamily);
    QBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    m_edit = new QLineEdit;
    QRegularExpression regex(R"(^\d{0,15}(\.\d{0,2})?$)");
    QRegularExpressionValidator* validator = new QRegularExpressionValidator(regex, m_edit);
    //m_edit->setValidator(validator);
    m_edit->setStyleSheet("background-color: #ED2442; color: white;");
    m_edit->setFont(customFont);
    layout->addWidget(m_edit);

    QComboBox* comboBox = new QComboBox();
    comboBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("opt1"));
    comboBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("opt1"));
    comboBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("opt1"));
    comboBox->setStyleSheet("background-color: #ED2442; color: white;");

    layout->addWidget(comboBox);

    QPushButton* okBtn = new QPushButton();
    //connect(okBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &QDialog::accept);
    okBtn->setFont(customFont);
    okBtn->setText("ОК");
    layout->addWidget(okBtn);
    setFont(customFont);
    //QPushButton* cancelBtn = new QPushButton("Отмена");
    //cancelBtn->setFont(customFont);
    //connect(cancelBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &QDialog::reject);
    //layout->addWidget(cancelBtn);

    QDateEdit* dateEdit = new QDateEdit(this);
    dateEdit->setCalendarPopup(true); 
    dateEdit->setDisplayFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"); 
    layout->addWidget(dateEdit);

    setLayout(layout);
}

Вот что выводит при неудачной компиляции, такое происходит только когда в QPushButton или в QComboBox добавляются русские буквы.


"не компилируется" - стоило бы привести лог сборки.

Используй QString для установки текста

QPushButton* cancelBtn = new QPushButton(QString("Отмена"));

Тоже не работает

QStringLiteral тоже пробовал

Тогда текстом добавьте лог сборки, меню, вид, окно вывода, или View, output

Ошибка связана с непонятным вызовом setFont(customFont); Надо указать объект для которого вызывается данный метод

Не с этим. Если это убрать ничего не изменится. Таким образом просто применяется на все дочерние виджеты один шрифт.

Что выводится в fontFamily ?
У меня вообще ошибка, связанная с вызовом .at(0) для QStringList. Но у меня 5-й Qt.
Да, еще у Вас "ОК" по-русски написано.

В qt6 отличается загрузка шрифтов. ОК написано по русски, но на кнопке по какойто причине просто вопросики. При этом если с этим шрифтом вводить чтото в line edit то все ок вводится. И если убрать шрифт ничего не изменится.
